# Allow row selection for disabled cells in WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid with some columns disabled (by applying IsEnabled=false style to the DataGridCell), so the cells are grayed and do not allow editing.

But I need to allow full row selection if the user clicks on the disabled cell.
Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @mm8: yes, works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: @karolis: yeah, very useful answer indeed...

Comment: why the question was put "on hold"? it does not seem "too broad" to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the `DataGridRow`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="dg_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

```
private void dg_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow row = sender as DataGridRow;
    dg.SelectedItem = row.DataContext;
}
```